# Chrome triggering keyring without being launched

Tags: google-chrome

I need to use Chrome for streaming, but ever since installing, i get multiple requests to enter keyring password - **Without launching Chrome** - this happens on start up, and multiple times during a session, without loading chrome.

Important - this password request comes without launching chrome, i get 3 requests on start, and then further modal requests, regardless of launching chrome

How do i block chrome from doing **anything** whatsoever, unless i tell it too? its a spectacular miccy take, for a program like a web browser to start itself up without permission and then demand permissions from a user...

I do not want to block keyring and will not be setting the password to blank or anything like that - i want Chrome to behave itself and not doing anything at all, until i  want it to..

Ubuntu 20.04 standard install

Comment: What is your current window manager?

Comment: standard 20.04 install with gnome shell